# Delete element via WebAPI + jquery (ASP.NET core)

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have asp.net webapi controller
Where I have delete method

Here is code of controller

```
 [HttpDelete("{id}")]
    public IActionResult Delete(Guid Id)
    {
        var reminder = _context.ReminderItems.Find(Id);
        if (reminder == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        _context.ReminderItems.Remove(reminder);
        _context.SaveChanges();
        return NoContent();
    }
```

I try to delete it via button on view and js function

Here is js function

```
function deleteItem(id) {
$.ajax({
    url: uri + '/' + id,
    type: 'DELETE',
    success: function (result) {
        getData();
    }
});
```

}

Here is button code `'<td><button onclick="deleteItem(' + item.id + ')">Delete</button></td>'`

So on rendering I get this `<button onclick="deleteItem(deb847f8-d98d-4075-be06-28482629e9cd)">Delete</button>`

When I click, I get error in console and row is not deleting.

> Invalid or unexpected token

[image]

If I try to do delete from postman, all okay with this id

So where can be my problem?

Comment: you need to put your id inside quotes to make it a valid javascript string : '<td><button onclick="editItem(\'' + item.id + '\')">Edit</button></td>'

Comment: how did your button onclick function magically render deleteItem when the code you show says the onclick function is editItem?

Comment: Yeah, this is works ! @J.Loscos